# Как открыть файл через python с правами админа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как открыть файл через python с правами админа?
Если что то у меня ОС Windows 10

Comment: runas, например

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В папке с Вашим файлом my_file.py создайте bat файл start.bat (название может быть любым, расширение должно быть bat)
В bat файле пропишите:

```
python my_file.py
```

Если питон не добавлен в переменную окружения, то нужно указать полный путь к интерпритатору python, например:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe my_file.py
```

bat файл можно запускать от имени администратора.

Или добавьте в начало my_file.py строки:

```
import os
os.startfile('cmd.exe','runas')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.startfile('имя_программы','runas')
```