# Как запускать программу от имени администратора?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Существует некая программа которую необходимо запустить с правами администратора. Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/750461/Как-открыть-файл-через-python-с-правами-админа

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как открыть файл через python с правами админа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/750461/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-python-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Comment: @finally Нет, там просто python запускают от админа, а мне нужно со скрипта python запускать от админа другие программы

Comment: вопрос "как открыть файл через python с правами админа" думаю включает в себя решение вопроса "как со скрипта python запускать от админа другие программы".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
import os
os.startfile('имя_программы','runas')
```

Comment: появляется окно запрашивающее права админа, возможно это обойти?

Comment: забавно.. низкокачествен как вопрос, так и ответ (:

Comment: @finally ахах мы нашли друг друга :)